# How to make such element from Navbar?

Tags: css, sass

guys! I make a navbar and ran into a problem that I don't know how to make mark up of the active tab.

[Screenshot of active tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ1m5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added am bottom shadow as well, and its looks like this -

[image]

**HTML CODE**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F0D0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d2a0d7;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #d2a0d7;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.active:before,
.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.active:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #d2a0d7;
}

.active:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #d2a0d7;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="navlink active">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="navlink">About</a>
  <a href="#" class="navlink">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d2a0d7;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d2a0d7;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="navlink active">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="navlink">About</a>
  <a href="#" class="navlink">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't what i need, please pay attention on bottom corners of active tab